# Remove all whitespaces except when space is part of an exact string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
<h1 class='' id='' title=''></h1>
```

I want to remove all whitespace except the whitespace after h1 so that the output looks like that

```
<h1 class=''id=''title=''></h1>
```

I tried to do it in two times

```
var string = "<h1 class='' id='' title=''></h1>";
var regexp = /\s/g;
var regexp2 = /(<h1)/g;
var string = string.replace(regexp, "").replace(regexp2, "$1 ");
console.log(string);
```

And I wanna know if there were a way to unite those two regexp in one.
I tried to do

```
var string = "<h1 class='' id='' title=''></h1>";
var regexp = /(?!<h1)\s/g;
var string = string.replace(regexp, "");
console.log(string);
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work that way. I want an explained answer on how to remove all whitespaces in my string except the whitespace in `<h1` knowing that this is one of the numerous `h1` lines and I also want to remove all `\n` and `\t`, thus why I'm using the `\s` in my regexp.

For the why question, I just wanted to remove inside <...> all whitespace after each selectors, but not the whitespace after the tag name like `h1` just for my own curiosity and to practice regexp. And also all return and tab chars. In a HTML5 document.

Comment: `s.replace(/(<h1\s+)([^<]*?>)/g, (m,grp1,grp2)=>grp1+grp2.replace(/(\w+='')\s+/g, '$1'));`. You cannot use this `.replace(/(<h1)(\s+)|(\w+='')\s+/g, '$1$2$3');` since it will replace `att=''` anywhere, not just inside `h1` tag.

Comment: why you need to remove those white spaces?

Comment: @MahediSabuj Learning purposes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did not fully understand the first part with the `m,grp1,grp2`. If you could just be more specific about what it does exactly please ?

Comment: Isn't there enough good enough answers or do you think mine is better?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: your answer seems to be working for me. I wanted to delete also all `\n` and `\t` anywhere in the string which will contain the HTML code but I think this will be another regexp.

Comment: Alright, I added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that you want to match a block of text and only remove something globally only inside one of the subparts. With regex, you usually achieve that by matching a whole block while capturing different smaller subparts with capturing groups (paired `(...)`) and, inside the `replace` method, use a *callback* anonymous method that accepts all these (and actually, more) groups.

Here is a regex matching the 'block's:

```
/(<h1\s+)([^<]*?>)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rA8sZ7/1).

Now, you can see there are 2 groups:

- 1) `(<h1\s+)` - `<h1` + one or more whitespaces
- 2) `([^<]*?>)` - zero or more chars other than `<`, as few as possible, up to the first `>` character.

You need to only remove the spaces between values and attribute names in the second capture, so, use

```
/(\w+='')\s+/g
```

and replace with `$1` (backreference to the value captured with `\w+=''`) *inside the callback*. The callback accepts the first argument as the whole match, then all the captured subtexts (you can also add an offset and input arguments, see [*`Specifying a function as a parameter`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)).

```js
var s = `<h1 class='' id='' title=''>Title1</h1>
<h1 class='' id='' title=''>Title2</h1>`;
var res_es6 = s.replace(/(<h1\s+)([^<]*?>)/g, (m,grp1,grp2)=>grp1+grp2.replace(/(\w+='')\s+/g, '$1'));
var res_es5 = s.replace(/(<h1\s+)([^<]*?>)/g, 
   function(m,grp1,grp2) { 
       return grp1+grp2.replace(/(\w+='')\s+/g, '$1');
   }
);
console.log(res_es6);
console.log(res_es5);
```

Note there are two result variables: for ES6 and ES5 syntaxes. The ES6 uses [*arrow function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of the anonymous method declared with `function`. Some older browsers might not like the arrow functions, and IE and Safari currently do not support them.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute `(\w+='')\` with `$1`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pD2tJ8/1).
The full `JS` code:

```
var string = "<h1 class='' id='' title=''></h1>";
var regexp = /(\w+='')\ /g;
var string = string.replace(regexp, "$1");
alert(string);
```

See [**a demo on jsfiddle.net**](https://jsfiddle.net/h6Lhveqr/).
As pointed out by @Redu, you could change it to `(\w+='')\s+` for multiple, consecutive whitespaces.

---

<sup>The question remains: **why?**</sup>

Comment: it might be better is your regex was `/(\w+='')\s+/g` in case there are multiple whitespaces

Comment: I edited my answer as I wasn't accurate enough on my problem.